# Posting on Facebook via PHP (issue with authorization/permissions)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I manage a few FB pages for local no-profit organization and would like to develop a PHP application that allows me to post on said pages via a custom interface.

I’m administrator of page X.
I’ve registered a dev account and created an app. 
I’ve set up a post script with my appID and appSECRET, and the response I get is: **OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action”.**

Now, I believe there are 2 issues.

1. I have to authorize the app to post on my page. And I have no idea
   where or how to do so.
2. Second is, the app seems to require more permissions, most likely
   publish_pages/publish_actions/manage_pages. In order to do so I have
   to describe my app in detail, provide a screencast and produce
   informations I do not have yet (as in, I’m merely attempting to make
   it work).

Facebook API guidelines seem to describe in detail how A and Z work, but not how to get from A to Z (or at least that’s the feeling I had). A lot of tutorials and discussions I found are several years old and irrelevant. Which brings me here. Can anyone with some experience, guide me and explain to me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

While creating/generating access token you need to add some permissions:

Goto https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. In the Application dropdown > Select the app created earlier > From Get Token > Get User Access Token> From select Permissions > check manage_pages, publish_actions, publish_pages > Get Access Token.

These permissions are required for posting to a page that you manage. So generate the tokens again and I think the error will be gone.